# What is this German/Italian badge?

Tags: world-war-two, identification, german

[image: small round badge]
I’ve come across some German badges, medals & awards etc but I’m struggling to identify this one.

Answer (score 13):

According to the site [unionemilitare.com](http://www.unionemilitare.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_16&products_id=244), this is an

> DISTINTIVO CONVEGNO ITALO-TEDESCO, ROMA MAGGIO 1938.

*Translation: ITALIAN-GERMAN CONFERENCE (or MEETING) BADGE, ROME MAY 1938.*

The site has a badge very similar to yours:

[image]

The site provides the following additional information:

> Distintivo smaltato e numerato assegnato agli organizzatori del
>   Convegno Nazionale Bande Cori Fisarmoniche Danzatori Popolari
>   organizzato a Roma - p.zza di Siena - nel maggio del 1938 ( XVI E.F.)
>   dall'O.N.D. (Opera Nazionale Dopolavoro) e dal P.N.F. Il distintivo fu
>   realizzato in ottone e "smalto livellato" dalla ditta " Castelli
>   Cerosa S.A." di Milano...

*Translation: Enameled and numbered badge assigned to the organizers of the National Convention Bande Cori Accordion Folk Dancers organized in Rome - Piazza di Siena - in May 1938 (XVI EF) from the UN (National Opera Dopolavoro) and the PNF The badge was made of brass and "level glaze" from the company "Castelli Cerosa SA" of Milan*

For the letters on the badge:

- PNF stands for [Partito Nazionale Fascista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Fascist_Party), (National Fascist Party)
- OND stands for [Opera Nazionale Dopolavoro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Nazionale_Dopolavoro) (National Recreational
  Club), "the Italian Fascist leisure and recreational organization for
  adults."

The performance took place on [May 6th](http://www.gabrielebrunini.it/dettagli.php?quale=7&quale_dettaglio=34) during a [state visit to Italy by Hitler](https://ww2days.com/hitler-pays-state-visit-to-italy-4.html), starting May 3rd 1938 and lasting 6 days. In addition to choirs, there were 50 musical bands and 900 accordions.

[image]

*La Corale Borghigiana was among those who performed on May 6th. [Image source](http://www.gabrielebrunini.it/dettagli.php?quale=7&quale_dettaglio=34)*

Below is a copy of the program for the May 6th performance.

[image]

*Image source: [Archivio Centrale dello Stato](http://search.acs.beniculturali.it/OpacACS/guida/IT-ACS-AS0001-0003667)*

---

Confirming the meaning of *Cri 114* (OPs picture) and *D 174* is difficult. As there is also a badge *B.A. 21* (see this [forum in Italian](https://www.lamoneta.it/topic/74363-info-su-medaglia/) for image), it is ***possible*** Cri = Cori (choirs), and D = Danzatore (dancers). The 'B' in *B.A.21* is most likely 'Bande' while 'A' may possibly identify a particular band. However, I can find no solid evidence to confirm this.

---

*Note: thanks to Tobia Tesan for the helpful comments*

Comment: OPs badge is numbered "C114"; the image in this answer is "D174" - any clue what the numbering sequences mean?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I've only found speculation on this so far, still trying to dig this up. Someone did contact the manufacturer about this but it appears they never got a reply. My guess is different groups of singers / performers were assigned different letters, with the numbers being for each individual in that group - but that's only a guess (so it stays as a comment for now).

Comment: @LarsBosteen: Those numbering appear to be stamped subsequent to manufacture, as the characters are slightly mis-aligned. (The "4" above is crooked, and the 1 and 7 are off alignment.) My best guess is that they are seating assignments stamped by hand on the medals by the organizers after delivery. That would also explain why the manufacturer cannot answer the question.

Comment: Another possibility: If the "D" is for *Deutschland*, the "*ri*" of "Cri" could stand for "*Regno d'Italia*", Italian for "Kingdom of Italy". I haven't figured out what the "C" would stand for in that case.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Found another badge - this one has *B.A. 21* on it...

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I'm thinking Cri = Cori, B.A. = Bande Accordion, D = Danzatore.

Comment: @LarsBosteen: Ah! "*Choir(s)*", "*Accordion Band*", "*Dancers*". Very good. I love Google Translate

Comment: The inscription `Converno Nazionale Bande Cori Fisarmoniche Danzatori Popolari Roma Piazza di Siena Maggio XVI` means `National symposium for marching bands, choir, accordions [players] and folk dancers, Rome, Piazza di Siena, May, year XVI of the Fascist era`.

Comment: `C.ri` is likely to be short for "Cori", i.e. "Choirs", especially since there is a number of other badges around with "B.A." or "D." instead, which suggests "Banda" or "Danzatore".

There is some good research being [carried out here](https://www.lamoneta.it/topic/74363-info-su-medaglia/), which points out among other things that the event coincided with Hitler's visit.

Comment: Is there any information about which song is depicted with those music notes?

Comment: @JAD Not that I've seen, but I'll ask my musician gf to strum it - problem is it's partly obscured...

Comment: @LarsBosteen whatever language that is (broken English? French?) they would *never* use "Bande Accordion" during the Fascist era. The italian word is Fisaorchestra, by the way; the inscription does not mention accordion *bands*.

Comment: @TobiaTesan So do you think it means 'Banda'? Or do you have any other ideas? I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: @LarsBosteen "B.A." *might* be "banda something", but I have no idea what "something" could be, possibly an adjective (in Italian it usually comes after the noun). I'm 100% positive A is not for "Accordion", though.

Comment: @JAD Since it's 2/4 and since it's a Fascist even with marching bands, I'd guess a military march or anthem. Doesn't appear to be one of the obvious candidates such as Giovinezza or the [Royal March](http://win.icscentro1.gov.it/sito_card/didattica/pdf_10_11/150_anni/150_html/contributi/contributi/spartiti/marcia2.jpg), though.

Comment: @TobiaTesan an anthem would've been my guess. Thanks for checking it out :D